# Newtonsoft json Deserialize complex object into class with different name

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

The JSON has complex objects with some having namespace information, how can I account for this in Deserialize. Simplified example below

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "urn:test:params:scim:schemas:extension:PersonBioExtension": {
    "dateOfBirth": "1900-01-01",
    "gender": "MALE",
  }
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
Rootobject user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(textBox1.Text);
```

Classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public TestScimSchemasExtensionBio testScimSchemasExtensionBio { get; set; }
}

public class TestScimSchemasExtensionBio
{
    public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use `[JsonProperty("urn:test:params:scim:schemas:extension:PersonBioExtension")]` on your `testScimSchemasExtensionBio` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alreaby mentioned in the comments, you can use the [JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) to change the names of properties when they are serialized to JSON.

Json string:

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "urn:test:params:scim:schemas:extension:PersonBioExtension": {
    "dateOfBirth": "1900-01-01",
    "gender": "MALE",
  }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("urn:test:params:scim:schemas:extension:PersonBioExtension")]
    public TestScimSchemasExtensionBio TestScimSchemasExtensionBio { get; set; }
}

public class TestScimSchemasExtensionBio
{
    [JsonProperty("dateOfBirth")]
    public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing:

```
string json = @"{
  ""id"": ""123456"",
  ""urn:test:params:scim:schemas:extension:PersonBioExtension"": {
    ""dateOfBirth"": ""1900-01-01"",
    ""gender"": ""MALE"",
  }
}";

Model model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
```